# BestPractices: Out parameters vs complex return types in methods

Tags: vb6, out-parameters, complextype

Using complex return type:

```
Public Type TimeType
    hours As Integer
    minutes As Integer
End Type

Public Function ParseTimeField(time As String) As TimeType
    Dim timeObject As TimeType
    Dim amountOfDigitHours As Integer

    If time = "" Then time = "0"

    If HasHoursAndMinutesParts(time) Then
        amountOfDigitHours = GetAmountOfDigitHours(time)
        timeObject.hours = CInt(Left(time, amountOfDigitHours))
        timeObject.minutes = CInt(Right(time, 2))
    Else
        timeObject.hours = 0
        timeObject.minutes = CInt(time)
    End If

    ParseTimeField = timeObject
End Function

Private Function HasHoursAndMinutesParts(time As String) As Boolean
    HasHoursAndMinutesParts = Len(time) > 2
End Function

Private Function GetAmountOfDigitHours(time As String) As Integer
    GetAmountOfDigitHours = Len(time) - 2
End Function
```

Call:

```
Dim timeObj As TimeType
timeObj = ParseTimeField(strTime)
```

OR using out parameters:

```
Public Function ParseTimeField(time As String, ByRef hours As Integer, ByRef minutes As Integer)
    Dim timeObject As TimeType
    Dim amountOfDigitHours As Integer

    If time = "" Then time = "0"

    If HasHoursAndMinutesParts(time) Then
        amountOfDigitHours = GetAmountOfDigitHours(time)
        hours = CInt(Left(time, amountOfDigitHours))
        minutes = CInt(Right(time, 2))
    Else
        hours = 0
        minutes = CInt(time)
    End If

    ParseTimeField = timeObject
End Function

Private Function HasHoursAndMinutesParts(time As String) As Boolean
    HasHoursAndMinutesParts = Len(time) > 2
End Function

Private Function GetAmountOfDigitHours(time As String) As Integer
    GetAmountOfDigitHours = Len(time) - 2
End Function
```

Call:

```
Dim hours As Integer
Dim minutes As Integer

Call ParseTimeField(strTime, hours, minutes)
```

BTW this is VB6 code =)

Comment: Let it return a TimeSpan and be done with it.

Comment: it is VB6 code :o But your answer is favorating the complex type.

Comment: The native VB6 type for times is Date http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262556(v=VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a single return type, do not use an out parameter to return it.

In general, I find multiple `ref`/`out` parameters to be a code smell. If you need to return data from your method, it is better if it is in one coherent object.

Comment: I agree with you. I hade a controversion with my team mates and the tend to use the out/ref params, because adding an extra type for the function result was overload for them. But when I look at the using of the function they have to define 2 variables all the time instead of one variable ;) . Nevertheless I had to give up and had to choose the out/ref style :s ... poor junior developers ...^^

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling we're going to see different opinions on this matter. Not sure there exists a best practice.

I usually prefer complex datatypes because I feel that is more in line with the original structure of functions where output parameter preceed the input parameters in the signature.  Basically I don't like out parameters - they're superfluous. Whenever there's two ways of doing a thing in a programming language, you complicate unneccessary (guess I'm gonna get killed by Perl-fanatics stating this). You return data with the return statement. Period.

This said, I still find myself using out parameters often when I need to return two parameteres that have no natural grouping - i.e. would end up in a class which would be used solely in the return value of this specific function.

Whenever there's three or more parameters in the return data, I never use out simply because I find the calling code to be excessive verbose - needing to Dim the variables (or var'em in C#)

Comment: I'd agree with this, except to add that when you have three or more out parameters that don't form a natural class, it is likely there is a problem with the design.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use out params as the universal style. Rarely need to implement helper functions that return UDT but these are usually private to the module so I can keep the scope of the UDT private to the module too.

In the latter case usually consume the retval like this

```
With ParseTimeField(strTime)
    Debug.Print .hours, .minutes
End With
```

... and most probably would keep `TimeType` with private scope.

Comment: why should I keep the TimeType in private scope?

Comment: You don't. But if you declare it public on a public class then you are publishing it to the world. Anyway, what do you think about the `With Method(...)` trick?

Comment: it's interessting :) I did not know that you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Definately a matter of opinion. I do use `ByRef` parameters from time to time, especially for utility functions which require a success/fail type scenario. For example, the `TryParse` functions in the .net framework do exactly this. Your parametrised function could look like:

```
Public Function ParseTimeField(time As String, ByRef hours As Integer, ByRef minutes As Integer) As Boolean
    'Do stuff'
    ParseTimeField = True 'or false depending on output success'
End Sub
```

Meaning you can call it like:

```
Dim hours As Integer
Dim mins as Integer
If ParseTimeField(time, hours, mins) = True Then
    'It worked'
End If
```

However as things start to get more complicated, and you're actually returning business items as opposed to doing logical commands, then a separate class and a return type is more desirable. It also makes calling AND returning easier to maintain.

Comment: the problem I have with this solution is that hours and mins is populated magically.

Comment: @Rookian yes you're right, it does seem a bit magic doesn't it?! Unless you're very aware of this code (i.e. you wrote it) then it's sort of an unnatural behaviour. It is usually expected to have a proper return type for this sort of code.

Comment: you changed the responsiblities of the function. You implemented a function in the "try" way. So you should rename the function to "TryParseTimeField". But that was not that what I wanted to have.